# Passing data from a sibling component to another Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to teach myself Angular 2 (well..it's actually Angular 4, but Google's numbering scheme is a little funky). Anyway, so far I've been able to figure out how to make everything work through examples from angular.io and questions answered here on stackoverflow. However, this one is stumping me.

So here's my problem, I'm trying to build a search page that can filter through a number of JSON data files using two different components, a search bar and a results page (if there's a better way to do this, I'm all ears). I've gotten the search bar to collect the data, and to get the data to pass via the router to the results page, where it will actually do the query and filtering, but I can't get the results page to read the data from the query string. Here are the relevant files.

**search-bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.css']
})
export class SearchbarComponent {

    langSelect: string = 'english'; // Default search language

    searchTerm: string;

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    searchForTerm() {
        let data: string = this.searchTerm + '_' + this.langSelect
        this.router.navigate(['/results', {searchData: data}]);
    }
}
```

**search-results.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { WordEntry } from '../../shared/models/word-entry';
import { DataRetrievalService } from '../../shared/services/data-retrieval.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './search-results.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./search-results.component.css']
})
export class SearchResultsComponent implements OnInit {
    searchData: string; // Two parameters separated by '_'. search term is on the left and the language on the right


    constructor(private dataSvc: DataRetrievalService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('starting!');

       this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
           this.searchData = params['searchData'];
           console.log(this.searchData);
       });
    }
}
```

**-----------Edit------------**

**search.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { SearchbarComponent } from './searchBar/search-bar.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './searchComponent/search.component';
import { SearchResultsComponent } from './searchResults/search-results.component';
import { DataRetrievalService } from '../shared/services/data-retrieval.service';

const SearchRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'search',
        component: SearchComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'results', component: SearchResultsComponent }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(SearchRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule,
        SearchbarComponent
    ],
    declarations: [
        SearchComponent,
        SearchbarComponent,
        SearchResultsComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        DataRetrievalService
    ]
})
export class SearchModule {}
```

These two files are sibling components in the search module, each in their respective folders.

My problem is that ngOnInit() does not look like it's being called at all as there is nothing being printed to the console, and the searchData class variable has nothing in it.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle ? is `search-results.component.html` called in you template in some way ?

Comment: Was the lack of selector in `search-results` intentional? Where is this component initialized, if so? Adding the module they're part of in the question may help. We'll need more info to find out the error.

Comment: Your SearchResultsComponent  has no selector, so nothing can cause it to load.

Comment: I'm using the module file to route to the page. I've updated the question to include the module code. I'll see about creating a jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm having issues with jsfiddle, so here is the github link https://github.com/Jeremy-Gebhart/MandoaSite/tree/development. It's in the development branch. Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure the cause-and-effect of what I did, but by extracting the SearchbarComponent and the SearchResultsComponent up into the main app module, instead of in a search module, and changing it so that the data was being persisted to a service between view transitions, I got it to work.

What I think was happening with the service [at first] was that the SearchbarComponent was talking to the app module service instance (since it's currently a part of the nav-bar), and the SearchResultsComponent was talking to the search module service instance.

Here are some of the relevant files:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './start/app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ErrorComponent} from './error/error.component';
import { NavComponent } from './shared/navbar/navbar.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './shared/app.routing';
import { SearchbarComponent } from './searchBar/search-bar.component';
import { SearchResultsComponent } from './searchResults/search-results.component';

import { WordEntry } from './shared/models/word-entry';
import { LexiconComponent } from './lexicon/lexicon.component';
import { DataRetrievalService } from './shared/services/data-retrieval.service';
import { TruncatePipe } from './shared/pipes/trunc.pipe';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule
    ],
    exports: [
        TruncatePipe
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ErrorComponent,
        LexiconComponent,
        TruncatePipe,
        SearchbarComponent,
        SearchResultsComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        DataRetrievalService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**search.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

    private _searchData = new BehaviorSubject<string>(''); // Initialize with emtpy string

    setSearchData(data: string) {
        // Fire the update event with the new data
        this._searchData.next(data);
    }

    getSearchData(): Observable<string>  {
        return this._searchData.asObservable();
    }
}
```

**search-bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { DataRetrievalService } from '../shared/services/data-retrieval.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'search-bar',
    templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.css']
})
export class SearchbarComponent {

    langSelect: string = 'english'; // Default search language

    searchTerm: string;

    constructor(private router: Router, private searchSvc: SearchService) {}

    searchForTerm() {
        let data: string = this.searchTerm + '_' + this.langSelect

        // Update the service
        this.searchSvc.setSearchData(data);

        // No need to change routes if you're already on that page, even if it's a no op.
        if (this.router.url != '/search') {
            this.router.navigate(['/search']);
        }
    }
}
```

**search-results.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { WordEntry } from '../shared/models/word-entry';
import { DataRetrievalService } from '../shared/services/data-retrieval.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './search-results.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./search-results.component.css']
})
export class SearchResultsComponent {
    searchData: string; // Two parameters separated by '_'. search term is on the left and the language on the right

    constructor(private dataSvc: DataRetrievalService, private searchSvc: SearchService) {
        // This should trigger anytime the searchbar is submitted
        this.searchSvc.getSearchData().subscribe(searchData => {

            // Don't even bother searching for an empty string
            if (searchData != '') {
                let parts = searchData.split('_', 2);

                // Clear the searchResults, otherwise it just appends to the list with each search
                this.searchResults = [];

                this.searchForWord(parts[0], parts[1]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**search-result.component.html**

```
<nav-bar></nav-bar>

{{searchData}}
```

I hope this helps someone down the line.